# Как возвращать const ссылку из методов класса? C++

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста, как возвращать const ссылку из методов класса?

```
class CCalculator
{
public:
    CRepository GetRepository() const;
```

....

```
CRepository CCalculator::GetRepository() const
{
    return m_repository;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очень просто

```
class CCalculator
{
public:
    const CRepository & GetRepository() const;
   // ...
```

и

```
const CRepository & CCalculator::GetRepository() const
{
    return m_repository;
}
```